# OrientDB Error in transactional processing of idseq.next()

Tags: java, orientdb

After doing a massive insert (more than 250,000 records) I'm facing the following error:

> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Error
>   during saving of record with rid #-1:-1

And after I'm also getting the following error:

> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSequenceException: Error
>   in transactional processing of idseq.next()

OrientDB log is:

> 2017-01-10 18:22:27:866 INFO  Loading configuration from:
>   C:/orientdb-enterprise-2.2.13_folder/config/orientdb-server-config.xml...
>   [OServerConfigurationLoaderXml] 2017-01-10 18:22:29:054 INFO  OrientDB
>   Server v2.2.13 (build @BUILD@) is starting up... [OServer] 2017-01-10
>   18:22:29:101 INFO  Databases directory:
>   C:\orientdb-enterprise-2.2.13_folder\databases [OServer] 2017-01-10
>   18:22:29:350 INFO  OrientDB auto-config DISKCACHE=1,979MB
>   (heap=1,979MB direct=1,979MB os=8,191MB), assuming maximum direct
>   memory size equals to maximum JVM heap size [orientechnologies]
>   2017-01-10 18:22:29:350 WARNI MaxDirectMemorySize JVM option is not
>   set or has invalid value, that may cause out of memory errors. Please
>   set the -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=8191m option when you start the JVM.
>   [Class] 2017-01-10 18:22:31:288 INFO  Listening binary connections on
>   0.0.0.0:2424 (protocol v.36, socket=default) [OServerNetworkListener] 2017-01-10 18:22:31:288 INFO  Listening http connections on
>   0.0.0.0:2480 (protocol v.10, socket=default) [OServerNetworkListener] 2017-01-10 18:22:31:335 INFO  Installing dynamic plugin
>   'agent-2.2.13.jar'... [OServerPluginManager]Error on installing
>   dynamic plugin 'enterprise-agent' java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.orientechnologies.agent.OEnterpriseAgent  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)   at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager.startPluginClass(OServerPluginManager.java:270)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager.installDynamicPlugin(OServerPluginManager.java:369)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager.updatePlugin(OServerPluginManager.java:211)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager.updatePlugins(OServerPluginManager.java:309)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager.startup(OServerPluginManager.java:95)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.registerPlugins(OServer.java:1184)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate(OServer.java:397)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain$1.run(OServerMain.java:46)
>
> 2017-01-10 18:22:31:350 INFO  Installing dynamic plugin
>   'orientdb-security-2.2.13.jar'... [OServerPluginManager]Error on
>   installing dynamic plugin 'security' java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.orientechnologies.security.OSecurityPlugin    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)   at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager.startPluginClass(OServerPluginManager.java:270)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager.installDynamicPlugin(OServerPluginManager.java:369)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager.updatePlugin(OServerPluginManager.java:211)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager.updatePlugins(OServerPluginManager.java:309)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager.startup(OServerPluginManager.java:95)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.registerPlugins(OServer.java:1184)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate(OServer.java:397)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain$1.run(OServerMain.java:46)
>
> 2017-01-10 18:22:31:366 INFO  Installing dynamic plugin
>   'orientdb-teleporter-2.2.13.jar'... [OServerPluginManager]Error on
>   installing dynamic plugin 'teleporter'
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.orientechnologies.teleporter.main.OTeleporter     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)   at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager.startPluginClass(OServerPluginManager.java:270)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager.installDynamicPlugin(OServerPluginManager.java:369)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager.updatePlugin(OServerPluginManager.java:211)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager.updatePlugins(OServerPluginManager.java:309)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager.startup(OServerPluginManager.java:95)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.registerPlugins(OServer.java:1184)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate(OServer.java:397)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain$1.run(OServerMain.java:46)
>
> 2017-01-10 18:22:31:506 INFO  Installing dynamic plugin
>   'studio-2.2.zip'... [OServerPluginManager] 2017-01-10 18:22:31:631
>   INFO  ODefaultPasswordAuthenticator is active
>   [ODefaultPasswordAuthenticator] 2017-01-10 18:22:31:631 INFO 
>   OServerConfigAuthenticator is active [OServerConfigAuthenticator]
>   2017-01-10 18:22:31:647 INFO  OSystemUserAuthenticator is active
>   [OSystemUserAuthenticator] 2017-01-10 18:22:31:710 INFO  Installed
>   GREMLIN language v.2.6.0 - graph.pool.max=50 [OGraphServerHandler]
>   2017-01-10 18:22:31:726 INFO  [OVariableParser.resolveVariables] Error
>   on resolving property: distributed [orientechnologies] 2017-01-10
>   18:22:31:726 WARNI Authenticated clients can execute any kind of code
>   into the server by using the following allowed languages: [sql]
>   [OServerSideScriptInterpreter] 2017-01-10 18:22:31:897 WARNI
>   {db=OSystem} Storage 'OSystem' was not closed properly. Will try to
>   recover from write ahead log [OLocalPaginatedStorage] 2017-01-10
>   18:22:31:928 INFO  {db=OSystem} Looking for last checkpoint...
>   [OLocalPaginatedStorage] 2017-01-10 18:22:32:866 INFO  OrientDB Studio
>   available at http://10.100.102.99:2480/studio/index.html [OServer]
>   2017-01-10 18:22:32:866 INFO  OrientDB Server is active v2.2.13 (build
>   @BUILD@). [OServer] 2017-01-10 18:22:32:866 INFO  {db=OSystem} Found
>   FUZZY checkpoint. [OLocalPaginatedStorage] 2017-01-10 18:22:32:866
>   INFO  {db=OSystem} Data restore procedure from FUZZY checkpoint is
>   started. [OLocalPaginatedStorage] 2017-01-10 18:22:32:866 WARNI
>   {db=OSystem} Record
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OFuzzyCheckpointEndRecord{lsn=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0,
>   position=862668}} will be skipped during data restore
>   [OLocalPaginatedStorage] 2017-01-10 18:22:32:866 INFO  {db=OSystem} 1
>   operations were processed, current LSN is
>   OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=862668} last LSN is
>   OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=862721}
>   [OLocalPaginatedStorage] 2017-01-10 18:22:32:866 WARNI {db=OSystem}
>   Record OFuzzyCheckpointStartRecord{lsn=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0,
>   position=862675}}
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OFuzzyCheckpointStartRecord{lsn=null,
>   previousCheckpoint=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=862628}}
>   will be skipped during data restore [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
>   2017-01-10 18:22:32:866 WARNI {db=OSystem} Record
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OFuzzyCheckpointEndRecord{lsn=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0,
>   position=862715}} will be skipped during data restore
>   [OLocalPaginatedStorage] 2017-01-10 18:22:32:882 INFO  {db=OSystem}
>   Storage data recover was completed [OLocalPaginatedStorage] 2017-01-10
>   18:23:01:773 WARNI {db=folder} Storage 'folder' was not closed
>   properly. Will try to recover from write ahead log
>   [OLocalPaginatedStorage] 2017-01-10 18:23:01:773 INFO  {db=folder}
>   Looking for last checkpoint... [OLocalPaginatedStorage] 2017-01-10
>   18:23:01:773 INFO  {db=folder} Found FUZZY checkpoint.
>   [OLocalPaginatedStorage] 2017-01-10 18:23:01:773 INFO  {db=folder}
>   Data restore procedure from FUZZY checkpoint is started.
>   [OLocalPaginatedStorage] 2017-01-10 18:23:01:773 WARNI {db=folder}
>   Record
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OFuzzyCheckpointEndRecord{lsn=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=905,
>   position=81046011}} will be skipped during data restore
>   [OLocalPaginatedStorage] 2017-01-10 18:23:01:773 INFO  {db=folder} 1
>   operations were processed, current LSN is
>   OLogSequenceNumber{segment=905, position=81046011} last LSN is
>   OLogSequenceNumber{segment=905, position=81046064}
>   [OLocalPaginatedStorage] 2017-01-10 18:23:01:773 WARNI {db=folder}
>   Record OFuzzyCheckpointStartRecord{lsn=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=905,
>   position=81046018}}
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OFuzzyCheckpointStartRecord{lsn=null,
>   previousCheckpoint=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=905, position=81045971}}
>   will be skipped during data restore [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
>   2017-01-10 18:23:01:773 WARNI {db=folder} Record
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OFuzzyCheckpointEndRecord{lsn=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=905,
>   position=81046058}} will be skipped during data restore
>   [OLocalPaginatedStorage] 2017-01-10 18:23:01:773 INFO  {db=folder}
>   Storage data recover was completed [OLocalPaginatedStorage]$ANSI{green
>   {db=folder}} Error on updating record #7:6 (cluster: plocal cluster:
>   osequence)
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OPaginatedClusterException:
>   Error during record update    DB name="folder"    Component
>   Name="osequence"  at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OPaginatedCluster.updateRecord(OPaginatedCluster.java:1119)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.doUpdateRecord(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:3067)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.commitEntry(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:3610)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.commit(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1418)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic.doCommit(OTransactionOptimistic.java:539)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic.commit(OTransactionOptimistic.java:104)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.commit(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2756)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.commit(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2725)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.commit(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:1315)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.executeRequest(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:581)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.sessionRequest(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:322)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.execute(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:198)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:77)
>   Caused by:
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.atomicoperations.ONestedRollbackException:
>   Atomic operation was rolled back by internal component, exception
>   which caused this rollback is : java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.sbtreebonsai.local.OSBTreeBonsaiLocal.findBucket(OSBTreeBonsaiLocal.java:1344)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.sbtreebonsai.local.OSBTreeBonsaiLocal.put(OSBTreeBonsaiLocal.java:232)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ridbag.sbtree.OIndexRIDContainerSBTree.add(OIndexRIDContainerSBTree.java:155)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ridbag.sbtree.OIndexRIDContainerSBTree.add(OIndexRIDContainerSBTree.java:45)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ridbag.sbtree.OIndexRIDContainer.add(OIndexRIDContainer.java:157)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ridbag.sbtree.OIndexRIDContainer.add(OIndexRIDContainer.java:45)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexMultiValues$1.call(OIndexMultiValues.java:154)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.doUpdateIndexEntry(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1869)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.updateIndexEntry(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1801)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexMultiValues.put(OIndexMultiValues.java:160)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexMultiValues.put(OIndexMultiValues.java:51)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionNoTx.addIndexEntry(OTransactionNoTx.java:341)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexTxAware.put(OIndexTxAware.java:116)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexTxAware.put(OIndexTxAware.java:40)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OClassIndexManager.putInIndex(OClassIndexManager.java:659)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OClassIndexManager.addIndexEntry(OClassIndexManager.java:554)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OClassIndexManager.addIndexesEntries(OClassIndexManager.java:541)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OClassIndexManager.onRecordAfterCreate(OClassIndexManager.java:419)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.hook.ODocumentHookAbstract.onTrigger(ODocumentHookAbstract.java:221)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.callbackHooks(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:1138)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.callbackHookSuccess(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:3134)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.executeSaveRecord(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2136)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionNoTx.saveNew(OTransactionNoTx.java:235)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionNoTx.saveRecord(OTransactionNoTx.java:168)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.save(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2623)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.save(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2507)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.save(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:102)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.createRecord(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:2737)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.createRecord(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:1718)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.executeRequest(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:542)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.sessionRequest(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:322)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.execute(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:198)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:77)
>
> DB name="folder"    at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.atomicoperations.OAtomicOperationsManager.endAtomicOperation(OAtomicOperationsManager.java:449)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.atomicoperations.OAtomicOperationsManager.endAtomicOperation(OAtomicOperationsManager.java:404)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.base.ODurableComponent.endAtomicOperation(ODurableComponent.java:116)
>     at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OPaginatedCluster.updateRecord(OPaginatedCluster.java:1116)
>     ... 12 more

Comment: Can you share the code to reproduce it?

Comment: Please upgrade to last 2.2.14.

Comment: @Lvca thanks! is there any known fix for this issue?

Comment: I don't recall which number, but there was a problem with the sequence of the plugin during startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Lvca commented Upgrade to OrientDB 2.2.14 solved my issue